# Newbie struggling to join 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables of purchases in the following format:

1. `date | company_id | apple_txn_amt`
2. `date | company_id | orange_txn_amt`
3. `date | company_id | pear_txn_amt`

There are multiple purchases/sales daily for many companies. I'm trying to join and group so there is only 1 date per company along with total fruit balance:

```
date | company_id | total_apple_balance | total_apple_orange_balance | total_pear_balance
```

I have built a query for a similar case earlier, and used 2 joins. But this was for only one company's data so I was only joining on date=date for each table. Process for each table was: gather buys, sells, union those two, union to a new table with generate_series() to insert 0s for days missing, calculate daily delta, and group by day to have a running total. Then something like:

```
SELECT 
  apple.day
  apple.total
  orange.total
  pear.total
  (apple + orange + pear) AS total_fruit
FROM apple
JOIN orange ON orange.date = apple.date
JOIN pear ON pear.date = apple.date
ORDER BY day
```

It's like I need to JOIN ON date *and company id* but from what I can tell this isn't possible.

Should I approach this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can add the company_id like

```
SELECT 
  apple.day
  apple.total
  orange.total
  pear.total
  (apple.total + orange.total + pear.total) AS total_fruit
FROM apple
JOIN orange ON orange.date = apple.date AND orange.company_id = apple.company_id 
JOIN pear ON pear.date = apple.date AND pear.company_id = apple.company_id 
ORDER BY day
```

But the design of your database isn't right, if circumstances don't require it.

you would not have 3 tables, you would have only one with Fruit type as another column, to differentiate them

Comment: Oh! You *can* do ANDs in a JOIN ON. Thanks! I agree this setup is not ideal, making it hard to work with. Perhaps I can build a different table with that setup like you said.

This works, but now I have lots of rows with one of the balances, but missing 1 or 2 of the others. I need to build a running total so each row(date) has the balance for every company_id. I'll keep cracking at it, thanks again!!

Comment: with the design i posted, ou have have an easy time 'SELECT date,customer_id, SUM(balance) FROM table GROUP byt date, Customer_id`, you can easily make day month years or decades sums

Comment: You have syntax errors in your answer you should fix (you're missing commas in your SELECT column list to separate the columns, and you can't add three tables like `apple 
 + orange + pear`).